# Will Disney Allow New Star Wars Legends Books?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, canon

So, I know that Star Wars Legends books are no longer considered canon (and the EU was a mess anyway). That said, I'm still hoping for more books from that side of the universe (Grand Admiral Thrawn, you're my only hope). Does anyone know if Disney will be allowing new books to be written under the Legends moniker for those that want to continue to explore that version of Star Wars?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### New books will not be labeled Legends, but it is possible that material from Legends (such as Grand Admiral Thrawn) will be introduced into canon

"Legends" is a label used for *past* EU works:

> Demand for past tales of the Expanded Universe will keep them in print, presented under the new Legends banner.

New books would therefore not be considered Legends by definition.

Furthermore, all *Star Wars* creative development is under the supervision of the [Lucasfilm Story Group](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Story_Group), so Disney will not allow other authors to write new non-canon works:

> Under Lucasfilm President Kathleen Kennedy’s direction, the company for the first time ever has formed a story group to oversee and coordinate all *Star Wars* creative development.

That said, Disney is not discarding the EU entirely. Authors may be allowed to bring Legends material into canon if the Lucasfilm Story Group approves it:

> While the universe that readers knew is changing, it is not being discarded. Creators of new *Star Wars* entertainment have full access to the rich content of the Expanded Universe.

So it is possible that Disney will bring more Legends material into canon (indeed, [Disney has introduced Grand Admrial Thrawn into canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/158187/31936)). This canonized material would obviously not be able to contradict other canon, so elements of Legends which contradict with current canon are effectively a dead end.

Source: [The Legendary Star Wars Expanded Universe Turns a New Page](http://www.starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page)

Comment: Notably, some of the new Console, PC and Mobile games will  **not be** canonical.

Comment: @Richard Do you know which ones? The only one I've followed is the new Battlefront, which was labeled "canon" the last time I checked.

Comment: [Several seem highly unlikely to be canonical](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Scene_Maker:_Rebels), and Battlefront itself will have a "[complicated](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Qr30EgqGVWEJ:www.ign.com/articles/2015/04/29/star-wars-battlefront-canon-is-complicated+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)" canon status.

Comment: I read the Thrawn trilogy and Shadows of the Empire just to see what was "so great" about then. I'm still wondering why people like them; they're boring and I hope the future canon is nothing like them.

Comment: I would love to see the The Darth Bane Trilogy make it into Canon. IMHO it's one of best EU works out there that doesn't seem to conflict with Disney canon.

Comment: @iMerchant Bane himself is canon but, yes, it's a great trilogy that I'd like to see make it into canon.

Comment: Albeit quite accurate, there is too much "Disney" and not enough "Lucasfilm" in this answer. The Canon Reset was not Disney's doing, it was totally the desire of Lucasfilm to simplify things and allow for new assets (movies, series, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

### Signs point to no.

From [the press release](http://www.starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page) regarding the new Disney vs Legends canon:

> Now, with an exciting future filled with new cinematic installments of Star Wars, **all aspects of Star Wars storytelling moving forward will be connected.** Under Lucasfilm President Kathleen Kennedy’s direction, the company for the first time ever has formed a story group to oversee and coordinate all Star Wars creative development.

If they will all be connected, they cannot be part of the Legends continuity. Everything must be coordinated through Kathleen Kennedy's department.

Comment: Please stop saying the New Canon as "Disney Canon". Disney had no say in what's canon and what's not.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, **in some circumstances** (presumably, rare)

Specifically, on October 2014 (after April 2014 canon Disneying), "[Star Wars: Imperial Handbook: A Commander's Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Imperial_Handbook:_A_Commander's_Guide)" by Daniel Wallace was released by " becker&mayer!" publisher as Legends.

> Although it was released after April 2014's creation of the Canon/Legends timeline and the established rule that any works released after that date are to be designated Canon, publisher becker&mayer! has confirmed that Imperial Handbook is branded as Star Wars Legends, meaning it is not part of the official Star Wars canon.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> While new material released on or after April 25, 2014 is generally considered canon, a certain amount of new material has continued to be released under the Star Wars Legends brand. This has included such material as the concluding comics in the series Star Wars: Legacy Volume 2[5] and Star Wars: Imperial Handbook: A Commander's Guide.[6] New material has also continued to be released for the game Star Wars: The Old Republic, despite the game being considered part of the Legends continuity and, in fact, no canon material being released for the Old Republic era in which the title is set.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Legends