# What are the differences between the Canon character Thrawn and the one in Legends?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, star-wars-rebels, character-similarity

Grand Admiral Thrawn was introduced in the third season of *Star Wars Rebels*. As far as I know, he's the only major character adopted from Legends to Canon. He was cold-bloodedly restrained, very intelligent, calculating and manipulating, and strategically clever.

Unfortunately I'm not aware of the Legends stories around Thrawn, originally created by author Timothy Zahn. Was he similar back in the 90's novels, or are there differences in the character between the two eras? I would assume Disney wanted to change at least something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In both the older novels and the new *Thrawn*, Thrawn is introduced to the Empire after a ship looking for smugglers finds the camp on a remote planet where he's been serving out his exile. Thrawn manages to get aboard the Imperial ship where the captain is so impressed that he takes him to Coruscant. The new book explains that Thrawn's exile was actually a ruse by the Chiss Ascendancy to enable them to gather intel on the Empire and ascertain whether or not it was a threat to them. The older Legends books never gave any indication that Thrawn's exile was anything other than that, and he certainly broke Chiss rules in the book *Outbound Flight*.

As far as personality differences, in *Thrawn*, he is somewhat politically naive and seems to greatly care for minimizing casualties among both sides. From what I remember, he's colder in the Legends books than he is in *Thrawn*. It's hard for me to say if any personality differences are due to the re-writing of his character, or if it's just because of the times when the books take place. *Thrawn* is set a while after Revenge of the Sith, while the old Legends books (with the exception of *Outbound Flight*) were set after Return of the Jedi.

Edit: The new book is just titled *Thrawn*, and the Legends ones I was referring to are *Heir to the Empire*, *Dark Force Rising*, *The Last Command* from the Thrawn Trilogy, and *Outbound Flight*.

Comment: Could you please provide book titles you ae referring to.

Comment: @TimSparrow Done. Unfortunately, the only book I have with me is _Thrawn_, so I can't get any quotes of his older personality/demeanour, but please let me know if there's anything else for me to add.

Comment: given that the character is written by the same author in all books, it is quite likely his character / personality is essentially the same